# PHP - Combine multiple arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have two functions, findNested to find substrings in a string and findOverlap that returns a combined ($consensus) string for overalpping strings. What I would like to do is create an array or work with the array that stores all the data ($all_data) and return the combined information if the $all_data[$i]['linear_sequence'] element in the array is nested or overlapped and if not use it's row. Each element in the $all_data array looks like $array1 and $array2 below. I was think to use array_merge_recursive to combine the data but I am not sure where to place it as many $all_data elements could be merged. But now it displays two times the same values in the new array and don't understand why.

```
    $array1=array ('linear_sequence' => 'QYDIKYTWNVPKIAPKS','E_ID' => 1416503, 'ant_source_organism_name' => 'Burkholderia pseudomallei K96243');

    $array2=array ( 'linear_sequence' => 'QQYDIKYTWNVPKIAPKSEN', 'E_ID' => 1409864, 'ant_source_organism_name' => 'Burkholderia pseudomallei K96243');



    function findNested($str1, $str2){
        $sl1 = strlen($str1);
        $sl2 = strlen($str2);
        if ($sl1>$sl2){
            if (strpos($str1,$str2) !== false) {
                return $str1;
            }
        }
        if ($sl2>$sl1){
            if (strpos($str2,$str1) !== false) {
                return $str2;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    function findOverlap($str1, $str2){
      $return = array();
      $sl1 = strlen($str1);
      $sl2 = strlen($str2);
      $max = $sl1>$sl2?$sl2:$sl1;
      $i=1;
      while($i<=$max){
        $s1 = substr($str1, -$i);
        $s2 = substr($str2, 0, $i);
        if($s1 == $s2){
          $return[] = $s1;
        }
        $i++;
      }
      if(!empty($return)){
        return $return;
      }
      return false;
    }

    function replaceOverlap($str1, $str2, $length = "long"){
      $min_overlap=9;
      $max_consensus=20;
      if($overlap = findOverlap($str1, $str2)){
        switch($length){
          case "short":
            $overlap = $overlap[0];
            break;
          case "long":
          default:
            $overlap = $overlap[count($overlap)-1];
            break;
        }   
        if (strlen($overlap)>=$min_overlap)  {
            $str1 = substr($str1, 0, -strlen($overlap));
            $str2 = substr($str2, strlen($overlap));
            $consensus = $str1.$overlap.$str2;
            if (strlen($consensus)<=$max_consensus){
                return $consensus;
            }
        }
      }
      return false;
    }

    /*str1=epitope1 and str2=epitope2*/

   function clustering($all_data) {
    $tmp=array();
    $result=array();
    //$tmp_keys=array('linear_sequence','E_ID','ant_source_organism_name','E_OBJECT_SOURCE_NAME','mhc_restriction','AS_TYPE','effector_origin','RFS','assay_score','subjects','responded','REFERENCE_ID');
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($all_data); ++$i) {
        $str1=$all_data[$i]['linear_sequence'];
        $row=$all_data[$i];
        for ($j = 0; $j < count($all_data); ++$j) {
            $str2=$all_data[$j]['linear_sequence'];
            $value1 = replaceOverlap($str1,$str2);
            $value2 = replaceOverlap($str2,$str1);
            $value3 = findNested($str1,$str2);
            if ($value1!=false){
                if(strlen($value1)>strlen($str1)){
                    print $i.' '.$all_data[$i]['linear_sequence'];echo"</br>";
                    print $all_data[$j]['linear_sequence'];echo"</br>";echo"</br>";
                    $str1=$value1;
                }
            }
            if ($value2!=false){
                if(strlen($value2)>strlen($str1)){
                    print $i.' '.$all_data[$i]['linear_sequence'];echo"</br>";
                    print $all_data[$j]['linear_sequence'];echo"</br>";echo"</br>";
                    $str1=$value2;
                }
            }
            if ($value3!=false){
                if(strlen($value3)>strlen($str1)){
                    print $i.' '.$all_data[$i]['linear_sequence'];echo"</br>";
                    print $all_data[$j]['linear_sequence'];echo"</br>";echo"</br>";
                    $str1=$value3;
                }
            }
        }
        //if(!in_array($str1, $tmp)){
        if (array_key_exists($str1, $result)!='True') {
            //$tmp[]=$str1;
            $result[$str1] = $row;
        }
        if (array_key_exists($str1, $result)) {
            //$tmp[]=$str1;
            $result[$str1] = array_merge_recursive($result[$str1],$row);
        }
    }
    foreach ($result as $epitope){
        print_r( $epitope);echo"</br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for `array_merge()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Comment: But array_merge() in the case of arrays with the same keys but different values will only keep the value of the first array key-value pair

Comment: How would you like the resulting array to look in the event we are merging two arrays that have two of the same key with different values ? Every key needs to be unique.

Comment: Now, I've been working on it for a while. And I have an array with unique keys, but for some reason it adds two times the same value. I will update my question now.